# In Ubuntu 18.04, is there an email program that has contacts?

Tags: software-recommendation, email

I tried Geary for email and it works fine, but it doesn't seem to have a way to keep contact info. Am I just not seeing it?

Comment: Have you looked at Thunderbird? It has an address book, and add-ons to sync it with Google Contacts.

Comment: `evolution` too is a choice (I suspect there are many). It's a gnome default and look at https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/ (search for "Contacts Management'.  There is no correct answer here, it's personal choice & your needs that will dictate the best choice for you.  I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this question on elementaryOS Stack Exchange](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4174/is-there-an-address-book-for-geary), Gnome Contacts cannot integrate with Geary.

Thunderbird is a free alternative email client. You should try it out if you have not. It offers a variety of plugins.